# How do I extract a GL texture id from a BufferRef using the gstreamer crates?

Tags: opengl, rust, gstreamer

I am working on a tool to use GL to render frames from a video onto a texture-mapped mesh.  I already have a GL app working with a single image (PNG).  Now I am trying to use gstreamer to decode the video.

I started with the [appsink example](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/gstreamer/gstreamer-rs/-/blob/160728965b82470f71d3ec254bb0bc664c16b422/examples/src/bin/appsink.rs).

I have gotten as far as piping the decoded video through `glupload` into an appsink.  Now I need to convert the `BufferRef` I get from `appsink.pull_sample().get_buffer()` into a GL texture id (a `u32`) so I can pass it to GL functions like `gl::BindTexture(gl::TEXTURE_2D, tex)`.  I used `set_caps()` on the appsink to ensure the buffer has feature `memory:GLMemory`, so it better be a texture and not off-GPU.

How do I extract a GL texture id from a `BufferRef` using Rust's `gstreamer` and `gstreamer-*` crates?

Comment: You can't map the data store of a (2d) texture but you can map a `PIXEL_UNPACK_BUFFER` buffer and transfer the data to the texture data source. See [Pixel Transfer](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Pixel_Transfer).

Comment: So far I have figured out how to use `gst_buffer_peek_memory()` to get a `GstMemory` which I can cast to a `GstGLMemory` (probably when `gst_is_gl_memory()` returns !=0 ) and then call things like `gst_gl_memory_get_texture_height` .  So far the buffer has 3 memories with heights 1536, 768, and 768, and their format is GL_RED, so I suspect it is YUV 420 planar.

Answer (score 2):

Retrieving the texture from a `GstGLMemory` in C requires mapping the `GstGLMemory` itself with a special `GST_MAP_GL` flag.  That specific interface for mapping an OpenGL texture does not currently have an analogue in rust yet.  There is some work in a related area within https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/gstreamer/gstreamer-rs/-/merge_requests/581 to help improve the situation with GStreamer OpenGL usage in rust.

If you only need readable access to the texture, there is an extension trait `VideoFrameGLExt` on `VideoFrame` that can get you access to the OpenGL texture.  There is a usage of `VideoFrameGLExt` in the glupload example in the `gstreamer-rs` repository available from https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/gstreamer/gstreamer-rs/-/blob/master/examples/src/bin/glupload.rs.  The `VideoFrameGLExt` trait is currently implemented within https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/gstreamer/gstreamer-rs/-/blob/master/gstreamer-gl/src/gl_video_frame.rs

Something like the following should work for read-only access:

```
// buffer: gst::Buffer
// info: gst::VideoInfo
if let Ok(frame) = gst_video::VideoFrame::from_buffer_readable_gl(buffer, &info) {
    if let Some(texture) = frame.get_texture_id(0) {
        // use texture somehow
    }
}
```

If instead you also need to write to the texture, that is currently not exposed and manual bindings would need to be written.

Comment: Or (for write access instead of writing manual bindings), you could call the C functions (from `gstreamer-gl-sys`) directly and do exactly what you would've done in C

Answer (score 0):

The code I am using these days is

```
/// This code is missing from the gstreamer rust bindings as of 2023-July
pub unsafe fn map_gl(buffer: &mut Buffer) -> Option<GstMapInfo> {
    let mut map_info = MaybeUninit::uninit();
    unsafe {
        let ret = gst_buffer_map(
            buffer.as_mut_ptr(),
            map_info.as_mut_ptr(),
            gst::ffi::GST_MAP_READ | gstgl::ffi::GST_MAP_GL as u32,
        );
        if ret != 0 {
            Some(map_info.assume_init())
        } else {
            None
        }
    }
}

pub fn get_gl_memory(bref: &BufferRef, idx: u32) -> Option<&GLMemoryRef> {
    let n = bref.n_memory();
    if idx >= n {
        return None;
    }

    bref.peek_memory(idx).downcast_memory_ref::<GLMemory>()
}

//
pub fn x(buffer: &mut Buffer) -> (GLuint, GLuint) {
    // the buffer isn't guaranteed to live on GPU until we map it using MAP_GL
    let map = unsafe { map_gl(buffer) };
    if let Some(mut map) = map {
        unsafe { gst_buffer_unmap(buffer.as_mut_ptr(), &mut map as *mut _) }
    }

    let gl_mem = get_gl_memory(buffer, 0).unwrap();
    let tex_id = gl_mem.texture_id();
    let gl_target = gl_mem.texture_target().to_gl();
    (tex_id, gl_target)
}
```

although the solution from ystreet00 works great if you have convenient access to the `gst::VideoInfo`.